# Saving string with accents in an Oracle Database with Coldfusion form

Tags: string, oracle, forms, coldfusion

I have a problem with an INSERT query and data saved in an Oracle database and displayed in our application.

I save data in a form with COLDFUSION in an ORACLE Database. The string contains accents. When the data are saved in the DB, the accents are not correctly saved and I can see "?" or "�".

Here is my query:

```
<cfquery name="qryAddNewPerson" datasource="#application.dataSource#">
    INSERT INTO REQUEST (DESCRIPTION,OPERATOR) VALUES (
        'Une desciption insérée',
        'Un opérateur ajouté'                   
    )
</cfquery>
```

In the DB I can see: 'Un op�rateur ajout�'

When I execute this request:

```
SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

I obtain **AL32UTF8**

And:

```
SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';
```

I obtain **AL16UTF16**

In my html I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app">
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

        .......
```

Comment: What are you using to look at the data after you insert it?

Comment: I have only retrieved data from the form with AnglarJS and I sent that to the Coldfusion query. After filling the form with 'Un opérateur ajouté'', data saving in the DB are 'Un op�rateur ajout�'

Comment: Log the value received to a file before running the insert. Is it correct? Is the query using cfqueryparam?